# how to create a side caption without Figure number?

Tags: floats, captions, sidecap

I am a very new Latex beginner. I would like to create a figure with side caption. However I would like to omit the "Figure" text inserted by default from Latex. For example, with the below code, I could produce the below figure. But I don't want the word "Figure 1.2" appears in the caption. How would you do that ? Many thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{sidecap}


\begin{document}

 \begin{SCfigure}
 %\centering
 \caption {my caption text}
 \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]    {myfigure}
 \end{SCfigure}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want only the phrase "my caption text" but not the rest of the caption?

Comment: Yes. I only want to delete "Figure 1.2" words, and keep "my caption text"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have figured it out: I used `\usepackage{caption}` and use command `\caption*{text here}` that would solve the problem. Cheers.

Comment: Not only does `\caption*` not produce the word "Figure", it doesn't increment the figure-counter either, so any following numbered figures are numbered correctly.